# Implementing sigprocmask(signals) in xv6

Tags: signals, xv6, sigprocmask

I am trying to implement sigprocmask in XV6. In that if the first parameter i.e how=SIG_UNBLOCK then as per my understanding the process mask must be removed. For that I was instructed to do

```
curproc->sigmask &= ~(*set);
```

But I am unable to understand this calculation.
Can someone please explain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you don't precise the type of `sigmask` or `set`, I will assume that they are 32 bits integer (`int`) and pointer on 32 bits integer (`int *`).

The line

```
curproc->sigmask &= ~(*set);
```

can be rewritten:

```
// get current mask
int mask = cupproc->sigmask;

int temp;

// get the signal(s) to set
temp = *set;

// invert the signal(s) to set to convert it signal to mask
temp = ~temp;

// update the mask with the signal to mask:
mask = mask & temp;

// save the new mask
cupproc->sigmask = mask;
```

So for instance, if you want to set the signal whose code is 3 (SIGINT in linux), you must first raise the third bit of an integer:

```
sig = 1 << ( 3 - 1) // to set only the third bit in sig.
```

Then call the function, `set` will be equal to `&sig`,

After line `temp = ~temp;`, temp will have all bits set but third

After line `mask = mask & temp;` all bits in `mask` will be kept but third that will be clear.